# Adding min and max date to blazor inputdate field

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, date, google-chrome, blazor

I am currently sitting with a quite frustrating issue here, which I thought should be quite easy to solve.

I have a blazor inputdate field where I have added a min and max date, but I am not seeing the desired end result.
This is how my code is setup:

```
   <InputDate @bind-Value="@ViewModel.DateTo" class="form-control"
      min="@datetoMin.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" 
      max="@datetoMax.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />

@code{
    DateTime datetoMax = DateTime.Now.AddDays(60);
    DateTime datetoMin = DateTime.Now.AddBusinessDays(-5);
}
```

The min and Max part is working fine but for some reason it looks like this on Chrome but not firefox:

[image]

"dd-mm-2023" Why is there a 2023 and not a yyyy? I noticed it looks correct when I only use either min or max but the combination of both adds the 2023 at the end.

Is there a way to fix this or just make the field empty until the user picks a date?

Comment: Probably because both min and max are in year 2023 so this part is already blocked to the only possible value.

Comment: It seems to be more of an HTML x Chrome browser question if you want to avoid this because this also happens in plain HTML, this is not Blazor related.

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine you're right. Is there in anyway possible to avoid showing the dd-mm-yyyy at all? even with the binding i have?

Comment: I don't know about HTML or built-in Blazor components but their should be external libraries that could suit you: for example [MudBlazor](https://mudblazor.com/components/datepicker#input-masking).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @T.Trassoudaine

I tested it via a MVC application, it seems this is not blazor related. The same thing happened in my MVC application:
[image]

I think chrome may recognize the datetime and calculate it by itself, in the screenshot you can see the main and max are both at 2023, so it displays the same year.

Also, I test it via the different year, which the issue is not showing:
[image]

Last, I tested it via static html file which the same thing occurs:
[image]

So I think it may has something to do with the bowser.

Comment: Yes, this does not happen on firefox when I tested it. The only solution is implement a 3rd party datepicker that has masking options built in